# keycloak using docker having issue with credential secret key

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

Currently, I am working on docker and docker-compose. I want to know that whenever I do **docker-compose down** and then after try to up all the service keycloak in which JSON file for the realm imported on the starter of keycloak server It started from zero as realm -> credential -> client secret key is different every time.

And one more I have to fire these two commands than only I can access http://ip:8080/auth

./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password ****
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database setup are you using?

If nothing is configured then Keycloak will fallback on H2 in-memory database. Unless you do some volume mapping any configuration and users will be deleted on docker-compose down.

You can also use environment variables to create a Keycloak user on startup, see [Keycloak docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/).
Example with volume mapping to persist h2 data and create user:

```
volumes:
  keycloak_data:
```

---

```
volumes:
  - keycloak_data:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
environment:
  - KEYCLOAK_USER=test
  - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=test
```

Comment: Right now I am using an embedded one but I want to use a MySQL container but that gave me the error "Failed to connect with database".

Comment: Ok then the volume mapping posted in my answer should help with persisting the changes. If you want do delete it you can do docker volume ls, find the name, then docker volume rm {name}.

I suggest looking over the Keycloak docker documentation, they have explanations of how to setup with mySQL. If you're still having issues you could update your post with the configuration you're using. It is a bit hard to diagnose issues without it